# Generator for $C_{0}(\Omega)$

Tags: operator-algebras

Let $\Omega$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, and suppose that the $C^{*}$-algebra $C_{0}(\Omega)$ is generated by a sequence of projections $(p_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Show that the hermitian element $h=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_{n}/3^{n}$ generates $C_{0}(\Omega)$.

I think it is quite clear that the $C^{*}$-subalgebra generated by $h$ is in $C_{0}(\Omega)$ but I can't show equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any positive linear functional $\tau$ on $C_0(\Omega)$,
$$
\tau(h) \geq \frac{1}{3^n}\tau(p_n) \quad\forall n\in \mathbb{N}
$$
Hence, if $\tau(h) = 0$, then $\tau = 0$. Conclude that $C^{\ast}(h) = C_0(\Omega)$

Comment: May I know what is the result you are using here to get the conclusion?

Comment: The following theorem : If $a$ is a normal element of a C* algebra, then there is a positive linear functional $\tau$ such that $\|a\| = |\tau(a)|$

Comment: Could you elaborate? I am not sure how to get the result from the fact that if $\tau(h) = 0$, then $\tau = 0$...